# Right way of testing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd, rspec

I'm new to rails, and I read recently on the internet (so it must to be true) that the TDD library that comes with rails is incompatible with RSpec, but also I read that RSpec is the right tool to do test.

So, my question is, if this is truth, what is the right tool to make test with rails: the rails TDD or RSpec? Or are this 2 tools total different  purposes?

Thank for the clarifications!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TDD means test driven development. It's a methodology, not a library.

Rails ships with Ruby's Test::Unit. It is easily replacable with other libraries such as Rspec, should you wish to do so.

There is no "right way" when it comes to which tool to use. It's all down to preference. I prefer Rspec personally...

Comment: I never said that TDD was a library, I spoke about the "TDD rails libs", the libs rails use to do testing in TDD style. But thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

RSpec is pure Ruby and a very good way to write tests for your code. It is easy to integrate using Gems and is straightforward to work with.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools for testing rails and other webapps from many different aspects. But if you are new to testing **I highly recommend you start with learning Rails own testing framework** before start using other tools.

Learning, and later mastering, one testing framework makes it easier in the future to understand pros/cons with other framework and make them work in unison.

You could start with testing the following things:

- Unit Testing your Models
- Functional Tests for Your Controllers
- Learning about Fixtures and how to load test data

I have seen many failed testing efforts, but I never saw them fail because they choose the wrong tool/framework. They fail because they don't know how to master the tools they use, and learn enough about the basics about testing.

Read more about Rails testing here.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

**Manual Exploratory Testing**
As much as I love automated testing it is, IMHO, not a substitute for manual testing. The main reason being that an automated can only do what it is told and only verify what it has been informed to view as pass/fail. A human can use it's intelligence to find faults and raise questions that appear while testing something else.
Read more about mixing Automated and Manual Testing in another of my answers here:
[What test methods do you use for developing websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260332/what-test-methods-do-you-use-for-developing-websites/2264499#2264499)