# How to start with testing a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, rspec, cucumber

I would like to write some automatic tests for my Rails 3 application.

I wonder how to start with that.

I've heard about Selenium/RSpec/Cucumber, and I guess there are many more options.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of these testing frameworks ? Which of them has the best documentation ? Which one is the most popular in the Ruby world ? And in the industry at all ?

I have the general knowledge of how to write tests. I just want to learn the appropriate testing framework(s) for testing Rails applications.

Please help me to decide with which testing framework to start.

Comment: All very good questions. IMO, there is such a lack of cohesion/understanding about so many aspects of Rails, esp with regard to testing.

Comment: Some good articles on [metabates.com](http://www.metabates.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tools for testing rails and other webapps from many different aspects. But if you are new to testing **I highly recommend you start with learning Rails own testing framework** before start using other tools.

Learning, and later mastering, one testing framework makes it easier in the future to understand pros/cons with other framework and make them work in unison.

You could start with testing the following things:

- Unit Testing your Models
- Functional Tests for Your Controllers
- Learning about Fixtures and how to load test data

I have seen many failed testing efforts, but I never saw them fail because they choose the wrong tool/framework. They fail because they don't know how to master the tools they use, and learn enough about the basics about testing.

Read more about Rails testing here.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

**Manual Exploratory Testing**
As much as I love automated testing it is, IMHO, not a substitute for manual testing. The main reason being that an automated can only do what it is told and only verify what it has been informed to view as pass/fail. A human can use it's intelligence to find faults and raise questions that appear while testing something else.
Read more about mixing Automated and Manual Testing in another of my answers here:
[What test methods do you use for developing websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260332/what-test-methods-do-you-use-for-developing-websites/2264499#2264499)

Answer (score 2):

**Selenium** is a framework to automate testing of user interface. Selenium script launches a browser window, goes to a web-page and manipulates page elements.

**RSpec** and **Cucumber** are tools for what is called "**behavior driven development (BDD)**". BDD is a development process where you have description of a separate feature, and some script (can be a Selenium script) that checks this feature. RSpec and Cucumber basically connect these two, so that when you run a test script, you see the list of features written in plain language and their testing status.

Selenium scripts can be written in a [number of languages](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#programming-languages), while Cucumber scripts use Ruby. Documentation is OK for all of them, some knowledge of programming language is required though.

Starting links:

- [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/);
- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/);
- [Testing rails applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say there is any one best set of testing tools out there; and the community definitely has not decided on any being standard in any way.

I highly recommend [The RSpec Book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book) from the Pragmatic Programmers-- about half of the book is on testing with Rails with Cucumber, RSpec, and browser simulators like Selenium. It's a comprehensive overview of the different situations you will find yourself in with Rails and what tools you might want to use in each situation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get started is using [TestUnit](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html). When you generate a model, view, controller using scaffolding it will automatically generate a testing folder for you containing a test environment setup file and tests, or you can add tests to existing models with a rails generator.

It is then a matter of reading the documentation on TestUnit, of which there is a fair amount.

For a next step, my personal preference is to use RSpec over Cucumber - I've found Cucumber hard to maintain, and whilst it is wonderful to have tests that are readable by your boss, I've found that most bosses don't really want to read or contribute to tests, and it makes for time-consuming development and is very 'bitty' - lots of small bits of text scattered in various files.

If you want to jump right in and begin using RSpec for Rails, then I'd recommend [Rspec-Rails](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails), which includes many helpers for asserting the correct behaviour of your application.

I could go on, but you've asked for 'where do I start' - there's two good places.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. You didn't say anything about Selenium. I guess that RSpec and Selenium intended for different types of tests. Is that right ?

Comment: Misha: RSpec can be used WITH Selenium if you are testing your app as rendered in the browser (Selenium is a browser driver).

Comment: What you use to pretend to be a browser is up to you - it works fine with RSpec. I use Webrat because I find it easier to set up.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of frameworks that help you test your ruby/rails code... the great thing is the dynamic nature of Ruby gives you a lot of flexibility.

I like to use RSpec to test the internals of my code, and Cucumber to test the application's behavior. So generally, RSpec will test models and methods, and Cucumber tests user interaction through the browser.

I highly recommend this pragmatic programmers ebook on [BDD using RSpec on Cucumber](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book).

- [Railscast on getting started in cucumber](http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber) (also called [cukes](http://cukes.info/))
- [Cucumber project](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber-rails)
- [Rails project](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails)

Comment: Note: I personally do not recommend selenium. I would go with Cucumber using Capybara to test browser/user interaction.

Comment: Jesse: Capybara can use Selenium as its browser driver if you're testing javascript; they're not mutually exclusive.