# web site testcase sample format

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, testcase

For web development ,

Can u send some sample test case xls report ,

Or is there any good open source plz refer ,

Is there any free automated testing for php web development ,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Automated testing tools for PHP:

- [phpunit](http://www.phpunit.de/) for unit tests.
- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a browser-based automated testing tool which can work with any language, but includes the ability to run with phpunit.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can give you test cases for your web site since every project/application/website is unique and deserves their own unique test cases. There is no "right" or "wrong" in testing. Testing is an art and what you should choose and how well it works out for you depends a lot from project to project and your experience.

But as a professional Test Expert my suggestion is that you have a healthy mix of automated and manual testing.

(Examples below are in PHP but you can easily find the correct examples for what ever langauge/framework you are using)

**AUTOMATED TESTING**

- **Unit Testing**
  Use PHPUnit to test your classes, functions and interaction between them.
  http://phpunit.sourceforge.net/
- **Automated Functional Testing**
  If it's possible you should automate a lot of the functional testing. Some frame works have functional testing built into them. Otherwise you have to use a tool for it. If you are developing web sites/applications you might want to look at Selenium.
  http://www.webinade.com/web-development/functional-testing-in-php-using-selenium-ide
- **Continuous Integration**
  Use CI to make sure all your automated tests run every time someone in your team makes a commit to the project.
  http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html

**MANUAL TESTING**
As much as I love automated testing it is, IMHO, not a substitute for manual testing. The main reason being that an automated can only do what it is told and only verify what it has been informed to view as pass/fail. A human can use it's intelligence to find faults and raise questions that appear while testing something else.

- **Exploratory Testing**
  ET is a very low cost and effective way to find defects in a project. It take advantage of the intelligence of a human being and a teaches the testers/developers more about the project than any other testing technique i know of. Doing an ET session aimed at every feature deployed in the test environment is not only an effective way to find problems fast, but also a good way to learn and fun!
  http://www.satisfice.com/articles/et-article.pdf

*This answer is (almost) identical to one that I gave to another question. Check out that question since it had some other good answers that might help you.*
[How can we decide which testing method can be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929924/how-can-we-decide-which-testing-method-can-be-used)